# Auto hot key 3 keys combination

Tags: autohotkey

I downloaded the auto hot key, and i really like this program.

But i'm getting in trouble, and could not find solutions at google. So i need to know the following:

1. How to create script with 3 keys, like `crtl` + `v` + `s` without interrupt the `ctrl` + `v` command?
2. How to disable all scripts for uknown time, like close the software and turn it on again sometime?

Thanks alot !

Comment: You should separate this question into two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using AHK_L v1.1.

1. You can use the [`#If` directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) combined with [`GetKeyState`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm#function), like this:

   ```
   #If GetKeyState("v")
   ^s::
       MsgBox You pressed Ctrl+V+S.
   Return
   ```

   Note that you need to press <kbd>V</kbd> before <kbd>S</kbd>.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by "disable all scripts for unknown time", but you can terminate a script from itself using [`ExitApp`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ExitApp.htm) or from another script using [`Process, Close`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm). Also, you can disable all hotkeys within a script using [`Suspend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm).